# How do you import and work with Emscripten FS in ES6?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I'm wondering how to work with the FS export module + data file from `file_packager`?

We're using the Emscripten to generate an ES6 export with the following:

```
emcc -Wl,-rpath,./wasm -Wl,-rpath,./wasm --rtlib=compiler-rt -Wl,-rpath,./wasm -Wl,-rpath,./wasm --rtlib=compiler-rt --no-entry -sALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -sFORCE_FILESYSTEM=1 -sEXPORT_ALL=1 -sLINKABLE=1 -sMODULARIZE=1 -sEXPORT_ES6=1 -sEXPORT_NAME=libfrutil
```

That library is working and we can import the whole WASM binding with ES6. The issue now is getting the FS library generated by the following line to work:

```
file_packager fs.data --js-output=fs.js --export-name=libfreerad --preload ~/Documents/Repositories/projects/fr-server/share/dictionary@/share/dictionary
```

So once those are available we're just doing:

```
import libfrutil from "../util/libfrutil-util";

const wasm = await libfreeradiusUtil(0);
const error = wasm.cwrap("fr_strerror", "string", []);
```

So I'm not sure what to do with the fs.data and fs.js scripts. Obviously the .data file needs to be available so it can be fetched however fs.js is confusing. Do I important it as a module similarly to libfrutil?

There aren't any examples on how to actually use FS with ES6 so it's extremely confusing to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution (and the most efficient) would be to use the `--embed-file` emcc linker flag.  This embeds the file data within the wasm binary itself (internally it calls the file-packager, but you don't need to run file-packager yourself).

Does that work for your use case?

Comment: Doesn't work here.  The data needs to be updated independently of the binary.

Comment: Hi scb100 thanks for the suggestion! My colleague Arran in the previous comment is mentioning we have a limitation that we can't ship the data file together. So we really need to be able to supply it as a .data separate from the fs module. Is there a way to do this?